# Src images of user folder in assets - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, src

Here I am looking for a way to use images in my react applications from a folder in assets/images, in a dynamic way.

Here is the tree structure of my assets folder.

[tree structure of my assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzcdp.png)

I would like to be able to import and use the image of the right user who is connected (I already get all the data).

But at the time of displaying it, the image is not found...

Here is what I tried:

```
<img src={require(`../../images/user_logo/${userData.logo_name}`)} alt=""/>
```

or

```
<img src={`../../images/user_logo/${userData.logo_name}`} alt=""/>
```

And a few other variations... but nothing.

Could it be a syntax problem or a webpack problem ? Knowing that I use in this component a static image that I import at the beginning and use without any problem later, the problem is not the path.

Thanks for your help

Edit:

My React component :

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import authAPI from "../services/authAPI";
import AuthContext from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import Logo from "../../images/VSLogo.svg";
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const Header = ({history}) => {

    const {isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated,userData} = useContext(AuthContext)


    const handleLogout = () => {
        authAPI.logout()
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
        toast.success('Vous êtes déconnecté !')
        history.push('/')
    }


    return( 
        <nav>
            <Link to="/"><img src={Logo} className="VSLogo"/></Link>
            <ul>
                <li className="navItem"><Link to="/teams">Equipes</Link></li>
                <li className="navItem"><Link to="/tournaments">Tournois</Link></li>
                <li className="navItem"><Link to="/esport">Esport</Link></li>
            </ul>
            {(!isAuthenticated && (
                <>
                    <Link to="/register" className="signUpBtn">S'inscrire</Link>
                    <Link to="/login" className="connexionBtn">Se connecter</Link>
                </>
            )) || (
                <>
                    <img src={`../../images/user_logo/${userData.logo_name}`} alt=""/>
                    <button onClick={handleLogout} className="connexionBtn">Déconnexion</button>  
                </>
            )}
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

My Webpack config (it's webpack encore)

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .splitEntryChunks()

    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    .enableSassLoader()

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',

        //to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/

    })   

    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: when using webpack + webpack file-loader, you would include the image in your react component with the `import` statement. Can you share your react component file and your webpack.config.js file? Example here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/

Comment: I think I see your problem. You're not actually using webpack's file-loader to include this image in your bundle. Webpack's parser looks for import statements, and if an import statement's path points to an image file webpack's file-loader can include that in your bundle. Instead you're creating an `img` dom node with a src attribute that has the literal value `../../images/user_logo/whatever_user_data_logo_name_is` - try opening dev tools in your browser and inspect the network requests. You'll probably see 404's corresponding to the images you're trying to load.

Comment: Yes i have 404 error, but i don't know how to fix this... all my attempts are failures, and i can't find how we make this with webpack encore & react

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding .default to the require, obviously it's due to a webpack modification again and to the es module.

```
var pathToLogo = require(`../../../public/images/user_logo/${userData.logo_name}`).default;
```